# Rails 3 ActiveRecord: UNION

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, union

Is there any way to use MySQL UNION in Rails 3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the only way you're going to get this to work by directly executing the query.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT REPEAT('a',1) UNION SELECT REPEAT('b',10)")
```

This returns an ActiveRecord resultset. If you want the results wrapped in a model do something like this:

```
MyModel.find_by_sql("...")
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a neat hack using select . 
For example if you want to make a union between User and OtherUser .

```
User.select('id from other_users union select id')
```

this will generate this SQL

```
"SELECT id from other_users union select id FROM users "
```

Comment: This what I called awesome, but just to warn some people that would make any mistake like what I did before.

By default, when do with pure SQL it should be `(SELECT id FROM other_users) UNION (SELECT id FROM users);` when take it to Rails, just don't write like `User.select("(id from other_users) UNION (select id)")` because it will generate `SELECT (id from other_users) UNION (SELECT id) FROM users`

Just saying

Answer (score 3):

```
Model.find_by_sql("your union query")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on this thread there are people working on a better solution for creating union queries in Rails:

https://github.com/rails/arel/pull/118

Meanwhile, I have written an small hack with which you'll be able to create simple union queries and do some filters with DISTINCT, ORDER BY and LIMIT:

http://coderwall.com/p/9hohaa